# Calculating upload speed issue in Delphi

Tags: delphi, file-upload

I use delphi 2010 and clever internet suite component i upload a file and want to calculate the upload speed..

i tried this code but it gives me "INF" in the label + the wrong speed !

whats wrong in that code?

```
private
  FBytesProceed : Int64;
  FTimeStamp : TDateTime;
  FSpeed : double;
end;

procedure TForm2.clHttp1SendProgress(Sender: TObject; ABytesProceed,
  ATotalBytes: Int64);
var
  LTimeStamp : TDateTime;
begin
  LTimeStamp := Now;
  if FBytesProceed < ABytesProceed then
  begin
    // calculating bytes per second
    FSpeed := ( ABytesProceed - FBytesProceed ) {bytes}
            / ( ( LTimeStamp - FTimeStamp ) {days}
              * 24 {hours}
              * 60 {minutes}
              * 60 {seconds} );
  end;
  FBytesProceed := ABytesProceed;
  FTimeStamp := LTimeStamp;

label1.Caption  := Format(' speed %n Kbps',[FSpeed / 1024]);

end;
```

Comment: if LTimeStamp = FTimeStamp you'd get a divide by zero error.  But this should be easy to track down with the debugger.  Take a look at FSpeed before you assign it to the caption.  Keep in mind since you are using 'now', the resolution of default timers in Windows is not very high, so its possible you'd get the same result if called in a tight loop.

Comment: you are right, the  LTimeStamp = FTimeStamp thats the problem ,honestly i have no idea how i solve that or code any alternative ? any tips please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you encountered, the resolution of the system timer isnt very good.  I seem to recall that it can be as low as 50ms.  Here's two ways to get around this, some of it depends on how your program is structured.

One, you can use a regular TTimer set to 2 second or whatever interval you'd like.  Each time that fires you get the byte count, compare it to the last time the timing event fired, and set the caption with the upload rate.  This would obviously only work if you're dealing with non-blocking uploads.  If you dont want to use a TTimer, you can also do this in a separate thread, and have that check the upload every couple of seconds.

Another way is to keep doing what you are doing, but only update the upload rate after a second.  What I'd recommend is using GetTickCount() instead of Now() (since you dont actually need the date, just a counter).  GetTickCount() brings back an integer representing milliseconds, not a floating point value.  Start a byte count at 0.  For every chunk that gets uploaded, add that amount to the byte count.  Then check the tick count.  If a second has passed since the last caption update, update the caption and set the byte count back to zero and record what the tick count was for the next time a chunk is uploaded.

(just some pseudo-code to illustrate what I'm talking about in the 2nd option)

```
t := GetTickCount();
n := t - LastTick;
if (n > 2000) then  //2 seconds
begin
    rate := ByteCount / n;

    caption := format(....);

    LastTick := t;
    ByteCount := 0;     
end;
```

Comment: Diagnostics.TStopwatch is what's needed rather than GetTickCount. +1 The right way to tackle this is to update less frequently, and calculate download speed over a longer range. I'd update maybe every 2-5 seconds, but calculate based on potentially a longer interval.

Answer (score 0):

"Now" is not a good timer to use. Something like GetTickCount is more accurate. GetTickCount is useful because it gives a value in ms since the system started up and is very fast. It's also better to look at longer period of time. I did something like this a while back and if you don't use some sort of window your speed ends up jagging all over the show. I found that it's best to keep the last x number of values and then use these to calculate the performance. It gives much smoother feedback to the user.

For example, something like this should work (using 10 values):

```
type
  TDataBlock = record
    DataTransferred: Int64;
    TimerTick: Cardinal;
  end;

  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    ...
  private
    FBlocks: TList<TDataBlock>;
    FLastAmount: Integer;
    FPreviousProceed: Int64;
    FPreviousTickCount: Cardinal;
    ...
  end;

  procedure TForm2.clHttp1SendProgress(Sender: TObject; ABytesProceed,
      ATotalBytes: Int64);
  var
    CheckTickCount: Cardinal;
    DataBlock: TDataBlock;
    Speed: Int64;
    TotalTicks: Cardinal;
    TotalData: Int64;
  begin
    CheckTickCount := GetTickCount;
    DataBlock.DataTransferred := ABytesProceed - FPreviousProceed;
    DataBlock.TimerTick := CheckTickCount - FPreviousTickCount;
    FBlocks.Add(DataBlock);
    if FBlocks.Count > 10 then
      FBlocks.Delete(0); // Make sure we keep our window at the last 10 values

    TotalTicks := 0;
    TotalData := 0;
    for DataBlock in FBlocks do
    begin
      TotalTicks := TotalTicks + DataBlock.TimerTick;
      TotalData := TotalData + DataBlock.DataTransferred;
    end;

    // calculating bytes per second
    Speed := TotalData {bytes} * 1000 div TotalTicks {ms};

    label1.Caption  := Format(' speed %n Kbps',[Speed / 1024]);
    FPreviousProceed := ABytesProceed;
    FPreviousTickCount := CheckTickCount;
  end;
```

You will obviously need to create your list and initialize all of the variables before you start.